# ffmpeg failed to pull local rtmp stream

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, server, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm relatively new to this workflow and this might be a simple problem to solve. However, I haven't found answers that matched exactly with my question. I've set up my nginx server with rtmp module and for testing purposes I used the following command to publish my stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <example.mp4> -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream
```

After that, I launched up my application which is supposed to read the stream from the nginx server and it failed at

```
avformat_open_input(&ctx, szFilePath, NULL, NULL);
```

The returned error code is -5 and it signifies I/O issue. The `szFilePath` I passed in is `rtmp://localhost/show/stream` and I assume this will automatically work since it works when I tried to play some mp4 sample files online. I also tried `rtmp://localhost:1935/show/stream` and vice versa. I could view the stream being played in VLC but I can't open it in the code. I'm not really sure what happened here. I feel like this isn't necessarily a complicated issue but I don't know where to start looking for possibles causes. I'd appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: There looks to me an issue with your ffmpeg command. Specifically `-acodec aac`

Comment: Why would that be an issue in this case?

Comment: Also I found something extremely interesting by accident. If I setup two applications for rtmp in nginx config file, letting one read the input stream and redirect the stream to the other rtmp application using ffmpeg then everything work out fine with the I/O error.

Comment: Sorry I re-read your issue and my previous comment is irrelevant.